# Resigning as moderator

Tags: discussion, moderators

With sadness I wish to make you aware that I am stepping down as moderator from this site.

There are a number of reasons for this, but the primary immediate causes are [Stack Exchange's disgraceful treatment of Monica Cellio](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5193/9917) and new mandates [that will soon be added to SE's Code of Conduct](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/333967/300411).  I am not willing to donate precious hours of my life in order to support a for-profit company that is so openly hostile to what "[Be Nice](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/help/behavior)" means to me.

I do not expect to run afoul of the updated CoC in my personal interactions on this site, so I do not intend to delete my account, but at this point I'm not sure what my future involvement here will look like.

It's been an honor to serve this community as an elected moderator.  Thank you.

Soli Deo Gloria.

---

*Edit 2019-10-08:*

*Elsewhere I've posted some additional thoughts on [what I feel is the key issue](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/a/6738/21576).*

*I was also remiss in failing to make clear in this post the respect I have for the moderators and members of the community who have chosen to take a different approach to dealing with this situation.  This is a deeply personal decision and it's no surprise that we should come to different conclusions.*

Comment: Very sad, but understandable.

Comment: Cross link: [my own resignation](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6718/30). For the record I made up my mind a day before you but my post took longer to write.

Comment: Of more interest is what "Be honest" means to SE. They write, "Above all, be honest. If you see misinformation, vote it down." It looks like this will have to be revised...

Comment: SE staff better make sure not to make the remaining moderators aware of what really caused the resignations, lest they wake up to it too and resign. Sorry to see you go.

Comment: Thank you Nathaniel, for your service.  I wrote [an answer to Caleb's resignation](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/a/6735) that also includes you as well, plus some reflections on what I appreciate from the moderators on this site.  I hope you consider staying now that the company [has apologized and promised to take remedial steps](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/334551/an-apology-to-our-community-and-next-steps) although it may not be enough.  Thank you again!

Comment: @GratefulDisciple Thanks.  For your benefit and anyone else's who cares to read more about my views on all this, I've posted some [additional thoughts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/334736/300411) on MSE.

Comment: @Nathaniel.  I read [your answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/334736/300411) and now understand better why you're leaving.  It looks like this experiment of having a Christianity Q&A site on a secular company's dime doesn't quite work out.  Maybe other hosting specifically for religion should take up the cause, like [The Gospel Coalition](https://www.thegospelcoalition.org/) and [Patheos](https://www.patheos.com/) which came to my mind right away.  Or this can be a worthy challenge to some web developer active members on this site :-).

Comment: "*Victrix causa diis placuit, sed victa Catoni.*"

Answer (score 11):

I was pleased to see you get elected, and sorry that we'll lose your time and talents.

Thanks for your selfless contribution to this site.  You made a difference to at least one person: me.

*And Jesus Wept*

Comment: Thanks for you kind words!

Answer (score 9):

You will be sorrily missed as a moderator and good councillor of the site. It is a shame this whole scenario has taken place, but I truly understand your position.

It is certain that something is brewing in those of higher authority of the corporate leaders. It makes my stomach turn. My heart is sinking quickly as both you and Caleb are leaving as moderators. You both did a such a great job!

It is unfortunate that we can not put this on the main site for all to see.

Brother, we will truly miss you!

Comment: Thanks so much!